# Cant use framework view in storyboard

Tags: ios, frameworks, uistoryboard

I have created a `framework` from swift code, and it contains a few `UIView` `subclasses`. I can initialize it by code, but when I add it in storyboard, then when running I get an error:

```
Unknown class FindloFinalAugmentedRealityView in Interface Builder file.
```

Why is that? I was able to use this class in `UI` when it was not closed in `framework`

---

OK one change, I have found, that I need to specify a module for this to work. The only problem is that Xcode is not showing this module in list, I need to write it by my onw. Is this the only way this can work, or can I do something to make it show on the list?

Comment: Did you try checking the "Inherit from Target" underneath the module name.

Comment: this is actually setting the target as my project name, which is wrong

Comment: I have tested this on FacebookSDK and some other frameworks, and it seems not to work in any of these, so I guess there is no way to make it work?